# HomeKit characteristic value updated notification not called to remote device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-tv, homekit

I have this configuration:
 - iPhone A connected to a WiFi network
 - AppleTV (3th generation) connected to the same WiFi network
 - HomeKit accessory connected to the same WiFi network
 - iPhone B connected trough cellular

All the devices (iPhones and AppleTV) have the same Apple ID logged in and the WiFi network has internet connection.

The issue that we're facing is that changing a characteristic value from the iPhone A the iPhone B is not notified of that update.
Changing a value directly from the accessory only the iPhone A is notified and not the iPhone B.
Changing a value from the iPhone B the behavior is correct (accessory and iPhone A receives the update).

With iPhone B if I try to write or read a (readable,  writable and supportsEventNotification) property the change is correctly received by the accessory and by the iPhone A.

Why can't I receive the notification of the change on the remote device? Should I do something in particular to allow this notification process?